# ng-bootstrap Modal size

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

What is the best way to set/override a custom width for a modal?

It seems ng-bootstrap currently supports

> size: 'sm' | 'lg'

but Bootstrap 4 supports sm, md and lg.

Ideally I would like the modal to be responsive and adjust similar to container sizes. And on mobile have it go full screen.

**EDIT:** Bootstrap 4 _variables.scss seems to have a $modal-md setting but appears to be unused.

```
$modal-lg:                    800px !default;
$modal-md:                    500px !default;
$modal-sm:                    300px !default;
```

Answer (score 65):

The cleanest solution that I could find is to use the windowClass property.

I.e.:

```
this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent,  { windowClass : "myCustomModalClass"});
```

Then add the following to your global CSS styles. This is important as the style won't be picked up from your components CSS.

```
.myCustomModalClass .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 565px;
}
```

Comment: yes putting style in global css is important. I initially didn't and gave me some grief.

Comment: You can also use to relative width: `max-width: calc(100vw - 500px);`

Answer (score 59):

Try like this :

```js
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModelComponent } from './model.component';

export class Component {

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

    open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModelComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the effect for backdrop: 'static'?

Answer (score 44):

I found this as a good solution.

```js
this.modalService.open(MyComponent, { windowClass: 'my-class'});
```

**ng-deep** “shadow-piercing” descendant combinator can be used to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. In this case **modal-dialog** class.

```css
::ng-deep .my-class .modal-dialog { 
     max-width: 80%;
     width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

When you don't specify the `size`, the default value use `$modal-md` (500px).

All the 3 modals sm, md and lg are responsive and will display on full width (with borders) on mobile.

If you really want a new size, you can use a custom size:

```js
this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, { size: <any>'xl' });
```

With a css for this class:

```css
.modal-xl {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

EDIT: the xl size is now a standard size so the CSS.

Comment: This fails for me when running npm build.

Comment: error on Angular 5 because of unrecognised argument: `Argument of type '{ size: "xl"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgbModalOptions'. Types of property 'size' are incompatible. Type '"xl"' is not assignable to type '"sm" | "lg"'.`

Comment: I just add the <any> tag which is a workaround until the size type became '"sm" | "lg" | "xl" | string'.

Comment: Worked for me, don't understand why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

add following css in style.css file.

```
.xlModal > .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 1490px !important;
    min-width: 971px !important;   
    width: 95% !important;
}
```

Note : we can replace `.xlModal` with any name.

open modal with new created style.

```
this.modalService.open(content,{windowClass:"xlModal"});
```

Comment: But this is not working for me. I have done the same thing. What might be the issue, it's just considering the size:'lg'

Comment: wait i'll comment plunker.

Comment: works fine, be sure that your CSS file is loaded before the modal dialog

Comment: I had to alter this just a bit but this was the seed to the solution so thank you very much! `.xlModal > .modal-dialog,
.xlModal > .modal-dialog > .modal-content {
    width: 80vw;
    max-width: 80vw;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Add size xl on interface `NgbModalOptions`.

```
export interface NgbModalOptions {
   size?: 'sm' | 'lg' | 'xl';
}
```

Now use it while opening the modal
`this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'xl' });`

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it into a function like

component.ts

```
// accepts 'sm', 'md' or 'lg' as argument.
// default argument 'md'
public openModal( dialogSize: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' = 'md'): void {
  let modalOptions = {};
  if (dialogSize === 'sm' || dialogSize === 'lg') {
    modalOptions = { size: dialogSize };
  } else {
    modalOptions = { windowClass: 'md-class' };
  }
  this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, modalOptions);
}
```

component.css

```
::ng-deep .md-class .modal-dialog { 
    max-width: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

And call it like,

```
openModal(); //argument 'md'
openModal('sm'); //argument 'sm'
openModal('md'); //argument 'md'
openModal('lg'); //argument 'lg'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to djpalme and Kapil Thakkar answers, you will need to set the 'encapsulation' of your Component to `None` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315781/5516556)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-generic-view',
    templateUrl: './generic-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./generic-view.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a argument `class: 'modal-lg'`

```
open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModelComponent, { class: 'modal-lg', backdrop: 'static' });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, { class : "modal-xl"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see a lot of partial answers here. I wanted to put what worked for me in the hopes it helps someone else.

I used Kapil Thakkar's answer and YnadW's answer to get it to work. First and foremost, you need to add the Encapsulation part in order for the classes to take hold.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-generic-view',
   templateUrl: './generic-view.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./generic-view.component.scss'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then, I needed to tweak the CSS classes a bit to get the modal properly adjusted. You have to change both the .modal-dialog and .modal-content in order to get the sizing right.

```
this.modalService.open(modal, { windowClass: 'custom-window-class' });

.custom-window-class > .modal-dialog,
.custom-window-class > .modal-dialog > .modal-content {
   width: 80vw;
   max-width: 80vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using `xl` or `lg` or `sm`

```
this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, {
  size: 'xl' or 'lg' or 'sm', scrollable: true, centered: true,
  modalDialogClass: 'dark-modal'
});
```

You can use either one

```
openSm(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'sm' });
}

openLg(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' });
}

openXl(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'xl' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just wanted to used the `'lg'` size for the modal, but it didn't work, even using a custom CSS class didn't work either.

The way I managed to make it work was to add `NgbModalConfig` in my feature module providers array, and then, where the modal is called (`open`), I set the `size` and other values in the component's constructor like the following:

**module**

```js
import { NgbModalConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent, ...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [NgbModalConfig]
})
export class MyFeatureModule {}
```

**component**

```js
import { NgbModal, NgbModalConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private config: NgbModalConfig, private modal: NgbModal) {
    this.config.size = 'lg';
  }

  someEvent(): void {
    const modalRef = this.modal.open(MyOtherComponent);
    ...
  }
}
```