# How to change ngx bootstrap modal width?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, styles

How can I set the width to my ngx bootstrap modal, I've tried but like It is fixed?

Here's the html

```
    <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" 
     role="dialog" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
    label="Close" (click)="hide()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-left">
                    <button type="button" id="dialog_no" class="btn btn-
        default btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">No</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-right">
                    <button type="button" id="dialog_yes" class="btn btn-
     primary btn-block ladda-button" data-style="expand-right" 
     (click)="confirm()">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How can I set the width of the modal for buttons to be placed just on the edge of the modal, with lets say 5 px of border margin?

[image]

I haven't put any styling yet in my css file, even tho I've tried to modify the width but didn't I guess know how...

Answer (score 21):

On your method call for the modal, you can setup a configuration object with the ModalOptions class that also comes with ngx-bootstrap. Within that, the 'class' property allows you to pass classes which will be appended.

```
const config: ModalOptions = { class: 'modal-sm' };
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(YourComponent, config);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 11):

When creating a modal, pass your css class to options like this:

```js
this.modalService.show(template, { class: 'modal-lg' });
```

Answer (score 7):

similar to [@jgritten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108715/4099159)s response.

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
this.modalRef.setClass('modal-sm');
```

it sets the `max-width` to `300px`

Comment: I want to give a size as I wish . How to do that. please tell me.

Comment: @Kum you either overwrite the existing css classes, or add your own.

Comment: could you please give me an example ?

Comment: @kum check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258691/4099159) out.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the below style to overwrite the original dimension of modal

```css
::ng-deep .modal-dialog{
    max-width: 1200px !important;
    width: 1200px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" to your component decorator and then override the class with something like:

```
 .modal-dialog{
    max-width: 600px !important;
    width: 600px !important;
  }
```

Comment: it applies this specific width to my all models. I want to apply it in my one modal only.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Set Class**

```
let modal = this.bsModalService.show(ConfirmModalComponent, { 
         initialState: { message: 'คุณแน่ใจหรือไม่ว่าจะลบข้อมูล Voucher นี้?' },});

modal.setClass('modal-custom-style');
```

**And Custom CSS**

`::ng-deep .modal-custom-style { max-width: 1200px!important; width: 1200px; }`

Comment: You can edit all css in this modal
, Example : 
// --- Modal CSS -- //
::ng-deep .modal-custom-style {
    max-width: 380px !important;
    width: 380px;

    max-height: 290px !important;
    height: 290px;

    .modal-content {
        border: none !important;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use only CSS styles to change the width of the container.
Change **max-width** property for ***.modal-dialog*** class, in some cases for ***.modal-sm*** class.

Comment: I don't believe this works due to Angular's view encapsulation, since the `.modal-dialog` class is nested.

Comment: @user3777933 yes I have tried it. It is not working.

Comment: .modal-sm {
    max-width: 350px !important;
}

.modal-lg {
  max-width: 559px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `doucment.getelementsbyClassName` after you create the modal.  Then you can change the element `minWidth` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your ts file:
config: ModalOptions = { class: 'modal-lg' };
then pass config also in the show method of BsModal sERVICE

EXAMPLE:

```
config: ModalOptions = { class: 'modal-lg' };
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. In styles.scss...

```
.modal-lg {
    max-width: 559px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was ::ng-deep with .modal-content,
but only after I placed the !important property

```
::ng-deep .modal-content {
    max-width: 1080px!important;
}
```