# ng-bootstrap modal custom css needs ViewEncapsulation.None to work?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

So I wanted to use a fullscreen modal on certain screen sizes and I set about customising it via component SCSS file. Nothing worked and I started searching around.

Found some info:

- [ng-bootstrap Modal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977398/ng-bootstrap-modal-size).
- https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1309.
- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#options.

Nothing helped until I realised in their own example (last item on the list) they set `ViewEncapsulation.None` for the component containing the modal. I verified that removing the setting causes their example to stop working.

I just thought that it was not clear that you had to set the ViewEncapsulation option and wanted to create something for people who run into the same problem. I hope it is ok.